# Unable to change background color of multiple div onclick using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am unable to change background color of multiple div onclick using javascript. I made a loop but it is still not working.

```js
function abc(){
  var a = document.getElementById("main");
  for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    a[i].onclick= function(){
      a[i].style.backgroundColor="red";
    }
  }
}
abc();
```

```css
div{
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px; 
  border: 1px solid red; 
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
<div id="main"></div>
<div id="main"></div>
```

Comment: `a` contains a maximum of 1 element because you use `getElementById()`, try using classes and `getElementsByClassName()`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Pls read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pls use [stack overflow snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) instead of pasting the code as text. Pls format your code correctly, be careful of spellings and punctuations and also pls explain the question in detail in the body of the question.

Comment: You shouldn't be using id for multiple items. getElementById just returns the first one it finds. You should be using `querySelectorAll()` with a class instead of id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDs are unique. Use a class instead.

```js
let boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("box");
for (let i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
  boxes[i].addEventListener("click", () => {
    event.target.classList.add("bg-red");
  })
}
```

```css
.box{
  width:  100px; 
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red; 
  margin: 10px;
}
.bg-red{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

ID attributes **must** be unique but as an alternative you could use `data-id` ( dataset attributes do not need to be unique ) and reference that in whatever javascript function you have. It is simple to assign an event listener to the document and then delegate the `event` to the target DIV elements as below by inspecting the `event.target` - thus totally removing the need for ID attributes in the first place. `document.getElementById` is useful and has it's place - but where there are multiple elements that can be targeted there are better alternatives - `querySelectorAll` or, as here, delegated events. The same approach could be used if the `id` were replaced ( as suggested elsewhere ) with a `class` attribute

```js
document.addEventListener('click',e=>{
  if( e.target!=e.currentTarget && e.target.dataset.id!=null ){
    e.target.classList.toggle('filled')
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 10px;
}
.filled{
  background:red
}
```

```html
<div data-id="main">1</div>
<div data-id="main">2</div>
<div data-id="main">3</div>
```